# Presenting XML with xsl- TVGuide

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML file and i need to trasform it via xsl/t to a table.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<TVGuide start="2001-07-05" end="2001-07-05">
  <Channel>
    <Name>BBC1</Name>
    <Program>
      <Start>2001-07-05T19:00:00</Start>
      <Duration>PT30M</Duration>
      <Series>A QuestionOfSport</Series>
      <Title></Title>
    </Program>
    <Program rating="5" flag="favorite">
      <Start>2001-07-05T19:30:00</Start>
      <Duration>PT30M</Duration>
      <Series>EastEnders</Series>
      <Title></Title>
      <Description>
        Mark's health scare forces him to reconsider his future with Lisa,
        while Jamie is torn between Sonia and Zoe.
      </Description>
      <CastList>
        <CastMember>
          <Character><Name>Zoe Slater</Name></Character>
          <Actor><Name>Michelle Ryan</Name></Actor>
        </CastMember>
        <CastMember>
          <Character><Name>Jamie Mitchell</Name></Character>
          <Actor><Name>Jack Ryder</Name></Actor>
        </CastMember>
        <CastMember>
          <Character><Name>Sonia Jackson</Name></Character>
          <Actor><Name>Natalie Cassidy</Name></Actor>
        </CastMember>
      </CastList>
      <Writers>
        <Writer><Name>Nick Saltrese</Name></Writer>
        <Writer><Name>Julie Wassmer</Name></Writer>
      </Writers>
      <Director><Name>Stewart Edwards</Name></Director>
      <Producer><Name>Emma Turner</Name></Producer>
    </Program>
    <Program type="documentary">
      <Start>2001-07-05T20:00:00</Start>
      <Duration>PT45M</Duration>
      <Series></Series>
      <Title>Get Real with Casualty</Title>
    </Program>
    <Program>
      <Start>2001-07-05T20:45:00</Start>
      <Duration>PT45M</Duration>
      <Series>Lottery</Series>
      <Title></Title>
    </Program>
    <Program>
      <Start>2001-07-05T21:30:00</Start>
      <Duration>PT1H</Duration>
      <Series>Panorama</Series>
      <Title></Title>
    </Program>
  </Channel>
  <Channel>
    <Name>BBC2</Name>
    <Program>
      <Start>2001-07-05T19:00:00</Start>
      <Duration>PT1H</Duration>
      <Series>Snooker</Series>
      <Title></Title>
    </Program>
    <Program>
      <Start>2001-07-05T20:00:00</Start>
      <Duration>PT1H</Duration>
      <Series>HomeFront</Series>
      <Title></Title>
    </Program>
    <Program>
      <Start>2001-07-05T21:00:00</Start>
      <Duration>PT50M</Duration>
      <Series>WildAfrica</Series>
      <Title></Title>
    </Program>
    <Program flag="interesting">
      <Start>2001-07-05T21:50:00</Start>
      <Duration>PT40M</Duration>
      <Series>Taboo</Series>
      <Title>Nakedness</Title>
    </Program>
  </Channel>
  <Channel>
    <Name>ITV</Name>
    <Program>
      <Start>2001-07-05T19:00:00</Start>
      <Duration>PT30M</Duration>
      <Series>Emmerdale</Series>
      <Title></Title>
    </Program>
    <Program>
      <Start>2001-07-05T19:30:00</Start>
      <Duration>PT30M</Duration>
      <Series>CoronationStreet</Series>
      <Title></Title>
    </Program>
    <Program>
      <Start>2001-07-05T20:00:00</Start>
      <Duration>PT1H</Duration>
      <Series>Millionaire</Series>
      <Title></Title>
    </Program>
    <Program type="drama">
      <Start>2001-07-05T21:00:00</Start>
      <Duration>PT2H</Duration>
      <Series></Series>
      <Title>Hot Money</Title>
    </Program>
  </Channel>
  <Channel>
    <Name>Channel 4</Name>
    <Program>
      <Start>2001-07-05T19:00:00</Start>
      <Duration>PT55M</Duration>
      <Series>Channel4News</Series>
      <Title></Title>
    </Program>
    <Program>
      <Start>2001-07-05T19:55:00</Start>
      <Duration>PT5M</Duration>
      <Series>SlotArt</Series>
      <Title></Title>
    </Program>
    <Program>
      <Start>2001-07-05T20:00:00</Start>
      <Duration>PT30M</Duration>
      <Series>Brookside</Series>
      <Title></Title>
    </Program>
    <Program>
      <Start>2001-07-05T20:30:00</Start>
      <Duration>PT30M</Duration>
      <Series>Brookside</Series>
      <Title></Title>
    </Program>
    <Program>
      <Start>2001-07-05T21:00:00</Start>
      <Duration>PT1H</Duration>
      <Series>Swallow</Series>
      <Title></Title>
    </Program>
    <Program flag="favorite">
      <Start>2001-07-05T22:00:00</Start>
      <Duration>PT1H</Duration>
      <Series>AllyMcBeal</Series>
      <Title></Title>
    </Program>
  </Channel>
  <Channel>
    <Name>Channel 5</Name>
    <Program>
      <Start>2001-07-05T19:00:00</Start>
      <Duration>PT30M</Duration>
      <Series>MovieChartShow</Series>
      <Title></Title>
    </Program>
    <Program>
      <Start>2001-07-05T19:30:00</Start>
      <Duration>PT30M</Duration>
      <Series>FiveNews</Series>
      <Title></Title>
    </Program>
    <Program type="entertainment">
      <Start>2001-07-05T20:00:00</Start>
      <Duration>PT1H</Duration>
      <Series></Series>
      <Title>The World's Worst Drivers Caught On Tape</Title>
    </Program>
    <Program type="film">
      <Start>2001-07-05T21:00:00</Start>
      <Duration>PT1H55M</Duration>
      <Series></Series>
      <Title>Black and White</Title>
    </Program>
  </Channel>
</TVGuide>
```

I know probably the problem is in the xsl file. I am not an expert and I will really appriciate your help.

Here is the xsl file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:key name="hatchala" match="/TVGuide/Channel/Program" use="Start"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">

        <table border="1">

            <tr>hours
              <xsl:call-template name="tvchan"/>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>
              <xsl:call-template name="hour"/>
              </th>
            </tr>

        </table> 
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="tvchan">
    <xsl:for-each select="/TVGuide/Channel">

      <th>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select ="Name"/>
        </td>

      </th>
    </xsl:for-each>

  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="hour">
          <xsl:for-each  select="/TVGuide/Channel/Program[not(./Start=following::Start)]">
            <xsl:sort select="Start"/>
            <xsl:variable name="zman" select ="Start"/>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="Start"/>
              </td>

              <xsl:for-each  select="/TVGuide/Channel/Program[Start=$zman]">
                <xsl:variable name="name1">
                  <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="Title!=''">
                      <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                      <xsl:value-of select="Series"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>

                  </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:variable>
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$name1"/>

                </td>
          </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result should show a table with all the programs and they hours.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/99771726/table.png

thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, if you are using XSLT1.0, you could use a technique known as Muenchian Grouping to get the distinct start time of all programs. This involves setting up a key to look-up programs by their start element.

```
<xsl:key name="hatchala" match="Program" use="Start"/>
```

Note you don't necessarily need the full Xpath to the **Program** elements, as the key will look them up at any level (You would only quantify things if you had such elements at different levels, and wanted to restrict them).

Then, to get the distinct start times, you would look up the programs which happen to be the first occurence of that element in the key for their start time

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
   select="/TVGuide/Channel/Program
      [generate-id() = generate-id(key('hatchala', Start)[1])]" mode="header">
```

(The use of 'mode' will be clear shortly because the final XSLT will match **Program** elements multiple times).

I would also define a key to look up programs for a given channel on a given start time

```
<xsl:key name="hatchala2" match="Program" use="concat(../Name, '|', Start)"/>
```

Then, for a given start time, you would loop over all channels, like so....

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/TVGuide/Channel" mode="program">
    <xsl:with-param name="Start" select="Start"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

And then template matching this, could look up the program using the key

```
<xsl:template match="Channel" mode="program">
   <xsl:param name="Start"/>
   <td>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('hatchala2', concat(Name, '|', $Start))" mode="program"/>
   </td>
</xsl:template>
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="hatchala" match="Program" use="Start"/>
   <xsl:key name="hatchala2" match="Program" use="concat(../Name, '|', Start)"/>

   <xsl:template match="/TVGuide">
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <th>hours</th>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Channel" mode="header"/>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="/TVGuide/Channel/Program[generate-id() = generate-id(key('hatchala', Start)[1])]" mode="header">
                  <xsl:sort select="Start"/>
               </xsl:apply-templates>
            </th>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Channel" mode="header">
      <th>
         <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
      </th>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Program" mode="header">
      <tr>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="Start"/>
         </td>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="/TVGuide/Channel" mode="program">
            <xsl:with-param name="Start" select="Start"/>
         </xsl:apply-templates>
      </tr>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Channel" mode="program">
      <xsl:param name="Start"/>
      <td>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="key('hatchala2', concat(Name, '|', $Start))" mode="program"/>
      </td>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Program" mode="program">
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="Title!=''">
            <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="Series"/>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then the following is output

```
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <th>hours</th>
      <th>BBC1</th>
      <th>BBC2</th>
      <th>ITV</th>
      <th>Channel 4</th>
      <th>Channel 5</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th>
         <tr>
            <td>2001-07-05T19:00:00</td>
            <td>A QuestionOfSport</td>
            <td>Snooker</td>
            <td>Emmerdale</td>
            <td>Channel4News</td>
            <td>MovieChartShow</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>2001-07-05T19:30:00</td>
            <td>EastEnders</td>
            <td/>
            <td>CoronationStreet</td>
            <td/>
            <td>FiveNews</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>2001-07-05T19:55:00</td>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td>SlotArt</td>
            <td/>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>2001-07-05T20:00:00</td>
            <td>Get Real with Casualty</td>
            <td>HomeFront</td>
            <td>Millionaire</td>
            <td>Brookside</td>
            <td>The World's Worst Drivers Caught On Tape</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>2001-07-05T20:30:00</td>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td>Brookside</td>
            <td/>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>2001-07-05T20:45:00</td>
            <td>Lottery</td>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td/>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>2001-07-05T21:00:00</td>
            <td/>
            <td>WildAfrica</td>
            <td>Hot Money</td>
            <td>Swallow</td>
            <td>Black and White</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>2001-07-05T21:30:00</td>
            <td>Panorama</td>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td/>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>2001-07-05T21:50:00</td>
            <td/>
            <td>Nakedness</td>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td/>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>2001-07-05T22:00:00</td>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td>AllyMcBeal</td>
            <td/>
         </tr>
      </th>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Do note the use of **xsl:apply-templates** instead of **xsl:for-each** to avoid too much nested code, to try and make it easier to read.

If you want a version that mainly uses **xsl:for-each**, try this XSLT instead

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="hatchala" match="Program" use="Start"/>
   <xsl:key name="hatchala2" match="Program" use="concat(../Name, '|', Start)"/>

   <xsl:template match="/TVGuide">
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <th>hours</th>
            <xsl:for-each select="Channel">
               <th>
                  <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
               </th>
            </xsl:for-each>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th>
               <xsl:for-each select="/TVGuide/Channel/Program[generate-id() = generate-id(key('hatchala', Start)[1])]">
                  <xsl:sort select="Start"/>

                  <xsl:variable name="Start" select="Start" />
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$Start"/>
                     </td>
                     <xsl:for-each select="/TVGuide/Channel">
                        <td>
                           <xsl:apply-templates select="key('hatchala2', concat(Name, '|', $Start))" />
                        </td>
                     </xsl:for-each>
                  </tr>                  
               </xsl:for-each>
            </th>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Program">
      <xsl:value-of select="Series"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Program[Title!='']">
      <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should generate the same output. Note that I have left one **xsl:apply-templates** in, as it generates the benefits of pattern matching, and provides an alternative to **xsl:choose**.

Comment: If I want to write the xslt file with xsl:for-each how do I do it? appreciate the help.

Comment: I've added a xsl:for-each sample to my answer!